# How to write two *unaligned* multi-line braces on both sides

Tags: vertical-alignment, align, braces

I have a theorem which is about some 4 conditions, 3 of which are equivalent in one case, and some other three are equivalent in some other case, hence I would like to typeset something like this:

```
\begin{align*}
   equivalent if B -{ condition (1) \        
                    { condition (2) \\     }-  equivalent if A
                    { condition (3) \\     }
                      condition (4) \      }
\end{align*}
```

I can do one brace or the other, or both if one's scope extended the other or was disjoint from the other's. But what can I do in this case? Is it possible without hacking too much?

What about non-mathmode alternatives?

Comment: I'm not really sure you're helping your readers with this format.

Comment: @egreg: This is for a beamer presentation. I intend to display one brace first and the second later (well, actually, with $\Downarrows$ in between the conditions and "$\Uparrow$ if" instead of those "equivalent if", but still. Do you have any better ideas on how to do that concisely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\#}
\setstackgap{L}{.7\baselineskip}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
   &condition (1) &\\       
   equivalent\ if\ B - \smash{\left\{\Centerstack{\#\#\#}\right.} \, &condition (2) &\\
   &condition (3) &\!\!\!\smash{\left\}\Centerstack{\#\#\#}\right.}-  equivalent\ if\ A\\     
   & condition (4) &    
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a follow up, to make the conditions centered with respect to each other, I could use an `array` environment (or `tabular` for text mode), rather than `aligned`.  Also, because  `array` and `tabular` environments redefine `\baselineskip`, one has to set the stackgap to an explicit point value, rather than defining it in terms of `\baselineskip`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\setstackEOL{\#}
\setstackgap{L}{10pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\arraycolsep=.5ex
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{array}{rcl}
   &condition\ (1) &\\       
   equivalent\ if\ B - \smash{\left\{\Centerstack{\#\#\#}\right.} &condition\ (2) &\\
   &condition\ (3) &\smash{\left\}\Centerstack{\#\#\#}\right.}-  equivalent\ if\ A\\     
   & centered\ condition\ (4) &    
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

{\centering\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\tabcolsep=.5ex
\begin{tabular}{rcl}
   &condition\ (1) &\\       
   equivalent\ if\ B - $\smash{\left\{\Centerstack{\#\#\#}\right.}$ &condition\ (2) &\\
   &condition\ (3) &$\smash{\left\}\Centerstack{\#\#\#}\right.}$-  equivalent\ if\ A\\     
   & centered\ condition\ (4) &    
\end{tabular}\par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can I make the middle column align to center?

Comment: Also, thanks for the suggestion, works great (though I'd found that .8 gap works better).

Comment: Alternatively, how can I make this work with \tabular?

Comment: @tomasz  See revision.  I used `array` to achieve centering.  Changing to `tabular` is just a step from there.

Comment: @tomasz  See latest revision for text mode.

Comment: That's nice, but I'm bothered by the huge space on the left of the center column. How can I fix that?

Comment: @tomasz Fixed...

Answer (score 4):

This is a job for `\valign`! Although I don't think this will help readers much.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\valign{#\cr
  \vbox{\hbox{%
    Equivalent if $A$
    $\left\{\vphantom{\begin{tabular}{c} A\\B\\C\end{tabular}}\right.$%
  }}
  \vfill\cr
  \hbox{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
  Condition (1) \\
  Condition (2) \\
  Condition (3) \\
  Condition (4)
  \end{tabular}}\cr
  \vfill
  \vbox{\hbox{%
    $\left.\vphantom{\begin{tabular}{c} A\\B\\C\end{tabular}}\right\}$
    Equivalent if $B$%
  }}\cr
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that uses only `array`s to align the three parts. The outermost `array`, which is set up to have three columns, serves to "house" the three horizontal parts. Each horizontal part consists of *four* rows, but some of the cells in the left-hand and right-hand parts -- which are constructed as nested `array`s, each consisting of a single column -- are empty. The instruction `\null` is used to create empty cells.

The middle part is currently set up as a `tabular` rather than as an `array` since it would appear to contain mostly text. If that's not correct, i.e., if it's supposed to contain mostly math as well, you could could use an `array` environment for the middle parts as well. Conversely, if the left-hand and right-hand parts are to contain mostly text, you may want to use `tabular`s instead of `array`s to define their layout.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} %% for "\text" macro
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{c@{}c@{}c}  %% outermost array: 3 centered columns
\begin{array}{c} \left. \begin{array}{@{}c}  %% a pair of nested arrays
  \null \\ \text{equivalent if $B$} \\ \null
\end{array} \right\{ \\ \null \end{array}
&
\begin{tabular}{c}
Condition (1)\\
Condition (2)\\
Condition (3)\\
Condition (4)\\
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{array}{c}  %% another pair of nested arrays
\null \\
\left\} \begin{array}{c@{}}%
  \null \\ \text{equivalent if $A$} \\ \null
\end{array} \right. \end{array}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```